# Automatically change remote user with sshfs

Tags: linux, git, sftp, su, sshfs

I have two remote servers, **foo** and **bar**. On both servers I have a user **git** (with different uid and gid). Both servers are running Debian distributions. Both servers have their each others' **root** ssh public key in authorized_keys, so all ssh-related commands already work like a charm.

**git** accounts have been properly configured - the default shell is set to /usr/bin/git-shell, the repositories are working on **foo** (**bar** is still unconfigured in the matter).

I'm trying to create a "shared directory" between **foo** and **bar** using sshfs. On **foo** I have a directory /home/git. The directory belongs to user **git** (uid/gid 1000 in this case). Let's say I want to mount this folder using sshfs on **bar** at /mnt/foo-git.

In normal case, I would just use sshfs git@foo /mnt/foo-git (on **bar**) to mount the directory (or use fstab, which by the way is what I plan to do once I get the system working). However, git-shell effectively prevents me from invoking sftp-server and using the sshfs in the simplest way.

After fiddling around a little, I decided to use the root user to log in (through ssh), change the effective user with su -l, and start sftp-server. To achieve this, I created a simple script (on **foo**) /sbin/git-sftp-server:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/su -l git -s /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

And used the following option with sshfs (**bar**):

```
sshfs root@foo /mnt/foo-git -o sftp_server=/sbin/git-sftp-server
```

The command seems to work, however it does not really change the permissions of the session. When I create a file on **bar**, on **foo** the file appears with owner **root**. This becomes a serious problem, when git commands can't change the contents of the repositories, simply because of the basic Linux file access control.

Right now, I see two possible directions:

1. Try to force sshfs session with user **git**. This may require me to fiddle around the git-shell, but might not be impossible
2. Find a way to fix su-ing into user git from a root session

Either way, so far I couldn't find a good way to solve the problem, but I count on your advice.

**Edit:** OK, After reading @AlexStragies comment (and testing few other things) it turns out, that my solution is *somewhat* working. If I mount the filesystem through sshfs or fstab with +/- the following options:

```
root@foo:/home/git  /mnt/foo-git    fuse.sshfs  defaults,_netdev,uid=998,gid=998,IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,sftp_server=/sbin/git-sftp-server" 0 0
```

And then su -l into git user with a "normal" shell and create a file, the uid/gid of the file is set properly to git@foo. *However*, let's say I create a file /home/git/cat with user root@foo and privileges 644. User git@foo obviously cannot modify the file (permission denied, however I was surprised he can remove the file, but I guess that's possible because he has write permission to the folder). On **bar** machine, the file appears to be owned by the user **git**, with permissions 644, although it's real owner is root@foo. Now, both users **git** and **root** at foo can modify the file cat (with the changes reflected on machine **foo**) although the file is still owned by **root** with permissions 644.

This seems like either a weird case of privilege escalation, or a not-really-working workaround. So, my question now is: which one? And if the latter, then what can I do to properly respect the remote user's permissions?

Comment: if you ssh-connect to bar as user git, specifying a different shell, say /bin/bash, can you then sshfs mount the desired folder from foo in a subdirectory of your home on bar? Or can user git@bar only run the git-shell?

Comment: @AlexStragies I will investigate that more thorougly tommorow, although I don't see how exactly this helps. user git@bar can run other commands if I first log-in as another user, and then su -l onto him.
I see two problems with this approach. If I try to mount the directory as git@foo, I shall run into the same problems with git-shell restricting my commands. If I mount as root@foo, I need to authorize git@bar's keys for logging as root at foo, which might be a huge security risk...

Comment: @AlexStragies somewhat good idea showed that the case was indeed working, but in an unexpected way. I made an edit to the question with an extensive explanation.